# Select 10 of the highest and 10 of the lowest record in each section

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a product table with 3 columns; product_id, category_id and price.

| product_id | category_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100400 | 2 | 7646000 |
| 100702 | 2 | 4039000 |
| 101280 | 2 | 4018000 |
| 102454 | 2 | 9709000 |
| 102570 | 2 | 3937000 |
| 104500 | 2 | 5240000 |
| 136745 | 14 | 5192000 |
| 137085 | 14 | 4307000 |
| 140955 | 14 | 4020000 |
| 143575 | 14 | 4557000 |
| 143830 | 14 | 3659000 |
| 145037 | 14 | 2577000 |
| 145746 | 14 | 3255000 |

I need a sqlite query that return a table with 10 of the highest and 10 of the lowest record for each category_id.

I think this problem can be solved with combination of group_by and union.

Assume that we don't have duplicate in prices so for each category we have exactly 20 records. 10 of the highest price and 10 of the lowest.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear since you speak of "section" and don't have a field with that name. You have category, is that it ? Also your numbers are too big to quickly grasp what's happening. Maybe you could simplify, and for examples cause have numbers from 1..100 ?

Comment: What about ties? Say, you have for one category 50 rows, but they all have the same price. What would you want to happen?

Comment: Thank you for mention it, yes i mean for each category_id we should have exactly 20 records, 10 of the highest price and 10 of the lowest. price of each product is distinct, so we don't have any duplicate. @MyICQ

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Assume that we  don't have  duplicate and for each category we have. exactly 20 records. 10 of the highest price and 10 of the lowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just number the rows per category ordered by price, once in ascending order, once in descending order.

```
select product_id, category_id, price
from
(
  select
    product_id, category_id, price,
    row_number() over (partition by category_id order by price asc) as rn_asc,
    row_number() over (partition by category_id order by price desc) as rn_desc
  from mytable
) numbered
where rn_asc <= 10 or rn_desc <= 10
order by category_id, price;
```

With `ROW_NUMBER` we don't consider ties. So if there are 50 rows for a category all with the same price, we'll pick 20 rows arbitrarily. If you want to consider ties, you may use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead.